# How to init List of tuple and add item in scala

Tags: scala

why this is NOT valid?

```
    var a = List[(String,String)]
    a = a :: ("x","y")
```

basically i want to init a list of tuple and add a tuple to the list.

Comment: What's the error message you are getting? Hint: it already answers your question.

Comment: `value :: is not a member of (String, String)` so how can i add a tupple to the list.

Comment: So, what does the error message tell you? You are calling the `::` method on the tuple, not the list.

Comment: If you're not getting the hint, the problem is you're trying to add a List to a tuple (operators ending in : are right associative) and you want to add the tuple to the list. You can either use :+, as in the answer below or (more idiomatically, and more efficiently for List) add the element to the start of the list and not the end with `("x", "y") :: a`. But an example like this is in pretty much every Scala tutorial or guide when discussing Lists, so it suggests you're not using one. Probably acquiring one would be a good idea

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here you have two mistakes.

The first one is that you are trying to instantiate List which an abstract class

I believe that what you are trying to do is the following

```
var a : List[(String,String)] = List()
```

This will create a list of an empty list of tuples.

The second is that you are trying to add an element which is not actually a tuple so I believe that you should try the following

```
 a = a:+(("x","y"))
```

Here you are defining a tuples and adding it to your List a

Comment: thanks a lot i was just trying the lang. And it seems i have to think differently than my syntactic expectations.

Comment: Your instantiation isn't very idiomatic.` List.empty[(String,String)]` is probably the most idiomatic

Answer (score 15):

You can instantiate an empty `List[(String, String)]` in many ways:

```
val list = List[(String, String)]()
val list = List.empty[(String, String)]
val list : List[(String, String)] = Nil
val list : List[(String, String)] = List()
val list = Nil : List[(String, String)]
val list : List[(String, String)] = List.empty
```

Note, too, that the default instantiations of `Traversable`, `Iterable`, `Seq`, and `LinearSeq` all also return a `List`, so you can use those too, (e.g. `Seq.empty[(String, String)]`).

And then you can add elements using `:+`:

```
val newList = list :+ ("x", "y")
val newList = list :+ ("x" -> "y")
```

You were using the cons method `::`, which is used for prepending.  In Scala, methods that end in `:` are right associative:

```
val newList = ("x" -> "y") :: list
```

You can also call them using the regular dot syntax if you want them to be left associative, like normal methods:

```
val newList = list.::("x" -> "y")
```

The reason this method is right associative is because it prepends elements, allowing you to do things like:

```
val newList = ("x" -> "y") :: ("a" -> "b") :: list
```

and retain the expected order (the same order that it appears in the code).

Answer (score 1):

Simple straight way in declaration:

```
val l=List("type"->"number","min"->"2","step"->"1","value"->"2")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also write the add like this if you want to add to an existing Array :

```
var a : List[(String,String)] = List()
a:+=(("x","y"))
```